# Rectangular regions as text objects?

Tags: cursor-motions, custom-text-object

Is it possible to define a text object in vim that will act on a rectangular region?

For instance, suppose I have vertically aligned columns of text, like this:

```
column 1 co    column 2 col
lumn 1 colu    umn 2 column
mn 1 column    2 column 2 c
1 column 1     olumn 2 colu
```

Would it be possible to define a textobject `c` for columns, such that `dac` would delete a column, `yac` would yank it, `cac` would change it, and so on?

(I know about Control-V for selecting a rectangular region, and I know you can then use `d`, `y`, etc to delete, yank etc the selected region. But I'm specifically curious about what's possible using text objects.)

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely! Case and point: [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim)

Comment: @PeterRincker This is nice, but I wonder if it couldn't be simplified to take advantage of Kana's [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki).

Comment: Thanks, Peter, that's exactly the sort of example I was looking for.

Comment: @PeterRincker make this an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. @PeterRincker suggests the plugin [textobj-word-column](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim), which defines four text objects (`ic`, `ac`, `iC`, and `aC`) for word-based columns.

The idea behind this functionality is to create a function that defines a column based motion, and then to map this function appropriately to visual/select mode mappings and operator pending mappings. To use the above mentioned plugin as an example, it creates the following mappings:

```
xnoremap <silent> ac :<C-u>call TextObjWordBasedColumn("aw")<cr>
xnoremap <silent> aC :<C-u>call TextObjWordBasedColumn("aW")<cr>
xnoremap <silent> ic :<C-u>call TextObjWordBasedColumn("iw")<cr>
xnoremap <silent> iC :<C-u>call TextObjWordBasedColumn("iW")<cr>
onoremap <silent> ac :call TextObjWordBasedColumn("aw")<cr>
onoremap <silent> aC :call TextObjWordBasedColumn("aW")<cr>
onoremap <silent> ic :call TextObjWordBasedColumn("iw")<cr>
onoremap <silent> iC :call TextObjWordBasedColumn("iW")<cr>
```

Here `TextObjWordBasedColumn(...)` defines the column motion and is mapped to both visual/select mode with `xnoremap` and operator pending mode with `onoremap`. Note that the function is slightly complex in order to handle indendation and to find the appropriate motion boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible? Absolutely! Case and point: [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim).

#### How to make your own text objects

Typically visual mode is used to create a new text object. The visual mode can be line-wise, character-wise (typically), or visual-block. Here is the basics of what you will need:

- An unused key combination typically `a{char}` or `i{char}` where `{char}` is both descriptive and unused. e.g. `i/` as an example text object between `/`'s.
- Need a way to find the start of your text-object. e.g. `T/`
- Need a way to find the end of your text-object. e.g. `t/`
- Choose a visual mode. e.g. `v`
- Create a visual mode (only) mapping via `xnoremap`.
- Create a operator pending mode mapping that uses the visual mode mapping via `onoremap` and `:normal`.

Now for an example of our simple `i/` which creates a text-object between `/`'s:

```
xnoremap i/ :<c-u>normal! T/vt/<cr>
onoremap i/ :normal vi/<cr>
```

As long as you follow the basic ingredients you can create text-objects for all sorts of things.

#### Advanced text-object creation with vim-textobj-user

The [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin provides a common way to define custom text-objects in a more declarative fashion. For example here is a php tag text-object:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('php', {
\   'code': {
\     'pattern': ['<?php\>', '?>'],
\     'select-a': 'aP',
\     'select-i': 'iP',
\   },
\ })
```

For more help with vim-textobj-user see its help doc: `:h textobj-user-introduction`.

#### For more help

```
:h map-overview
:h visual-start
:h :norm
```

As well as the [Creating new text objects](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects) Vim wiki page.